# Default command al finalizar cualquier comando del Makefile

Tags: makefile, make

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación symfony, con docker-compose. He añadido un Makefile para simplificar un poco algunos comandos que suelo utilizar. Un ejemplo del makefile que tengo es:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

.PHONY: help
help: ## Display help
    echo "manual"

##@ symfony commands

.PHONY: clean
clean: ## Clean cache, logs, reports
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml exec server rm -rf report/* var/*

.PHONY: config-hooks
config-hooks: ## Configurate Git hooks
    git config core.hooksPath ./hooks

# mas comandos...
```

Actualmente, los comandos funcionan correctamente, y hacen lo que se espera. Si no pongo un comando, se ejecuta por defecto el `help` (ya que esta configurado con el DEFAULT_GOAL).

Me interesaría que, al final de la ejecución de cada comando, se mostrara por la pantalla un mensaje (por ej, "finalizado"). Puedo añadir al final de cada comando un echo con el mensaje, o llamar a otro comando, pero estoy buscando si hay alguna manera (tipo "DEFAULT_END", "FINALLY", "LAST_GOAL") para que siempre se ejecute un comando una vez acabado el que he ejecutado.

Alguien le suena que exista algo así?